# No Internet Available, sometimes

Tags: wi-fi

One week ago, my phone suddenly grew a very annoying problem with the Wi-Fi. Pretty much what happens is that my Samsung phone is working like normal for ten seconds. Then, the Wi-Fi disconnects and says "No internet available". If I manually reconnect it by tapping the Wi-Fi in settings and press connect, it connects back to the Wi-Fi. Then the cycle repeats ten seconds later.

Also, the cycle is not constant. Sometimes I have internet access for a few minutes, sometimes only for three seconds, but on mostly ten seconds.

Another thing, it's not my phone. My phone can connect perfectly well to all other Wi-Fis. It also not my router, for all other devices connect perfectly well to it. It has something to do with the specific connection between this phone and my linksys internet.

On a side note, I have a roomba connected via schedule to this phone. It hasn't automatically vaccummed since my internet-phone connection acted it.

EDIT 1: I have tried using the Wi-Fi fixer app and it did not work as desired. When the app is running, the same cycle occurs as described above. With the exception that every time the Wi-Fi disconnects, Wi-Fi fixer automatically reconnects.

This is a great step, as I get a somewhat more reliable internet connection. However, this means that every 20 seconds the "connected to Wi-Fi" pop up appears. It also means my internet goes in and out constantly. I also imagine the constant reconnecting to the internet causes a smaller battery life.

[image: A picture of a section of the cycling Wi-Fi connection shown in Wi-Fi fixer]

Answer (score 0):

[Wifi connects for sometimes then disconnects and then never connects](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93677/wifi-connects-for-sometimes-then-disconnects-and-then-never-connects?rq=1)

This question seems to be similar to your situation. OP reported that the problem was solved by using this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wahtod.wififixer&hl=en

EDIT:
Taken from [Wifi keeps disconnecting and reconnecting frequently](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/82088/wifi-keeps-disconnecting-and-reconnecting-frequently)

1.Dial *#0011#

2.Then press the menu button and select wifi

3.You'll notice an ON button

4.Turn it Off

5.Restart phone

p.s.: When you restart your phone, recheck if it's still OFF, if not repeat til it works.

Alternatively, you may want to try the possible solutions listed here: https://www.connectify.me/blog/fix-internet/how-to-fix-android-wifi-disconnect/

Comment: The app did not work. Further details on EDIT 1 in the post.